# Windows phone apps memory path on phone

Tags: apps, storage

I can't find the location of the windows phone app files on my phone. I can find the location in my computer (C:/...), which is synced. But can't find it in the phone.
The reason why I'm asking this is because although I have reset the game 'Dungeon Hunter 5' in my laptop, I am not able to reset it in my phone. Always end up with Lvl 25 character in my phone. So I want to delete the remnant files on the phone.

Thanks in advance.

PS Pl feel free to edit the question

Comment: You can't access app data on the phone. Have you tried reinstalling the game?

Comment: Yes. In the desktop, the game gets reset. But in the phone, it starts with the old game; even without logging in with facebook account.

Comment: Hm, this usually means your game state is being roamed between devices. You should contact the developer to see if there's a fix for that.

Comment: It's a long shot but if the app didn't ask for credentials maybe its using the Advertising id (in settings).  So reseting it could help. But I'm guessing.

Comment: What should I reset? Is it advertising ID? My advertising ID is already switched off.